# Shorter way to write this conditional statement?

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a better alternative then coding this:

```
String reps = status != null && status.sets != null && status.sets[index].reps != null ? status.sets[index].reps.toString() : '-';
```

I could also do this:

```
String reps;
try {
  reps = hasImprovedReps ? currentReps : status.sets[index].reps.toString();
} catch (e) {
  reps = '-';
}
```

But this way it's not one line and it's not a condition so I could use it in a `Text()`constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `?.` and `??` operators:

```
String reps = status?.sets?.elementAt(index)?.reps?.toString() ?? '-'
```